# How to set v-if property from the template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I was wondering whether its possible to set a property in a `v-for` from the template. Specifically, `story.verifyDelete` is not present in the original array, but my setting it to true on click doesn't seem to activate the `v-if="story.verifyDelete` just above it.

```
<div v-for="story in stories">
    <div v-if="story.verifyDelete == true">
      <div>Are you sure you want to delete this story?</div>
      <div @click="remove(story.id)">Delete</div>
      <div @click="story.verifyDelete=false">Cancel</div>
    </div>
    <div @click="story.state == 'published' ? read(story) : edit(story)">{{ story.title }}</div>
    <div @click="story.verifyDelete = true">Delete</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your test tell you?

Comment: I haven't set up any unit tests if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: I mean the simple execution of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects are not reactive by normal setters = or [] in vue.

In your click handler for the Delete div, you will need to do a set in order to have vue notice the value change

```
this.$set(this.story, 'verifyDelete', true)
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html